# SQL stored procedure with multiple Select statements

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am using a Stored procedure, which I just can execute not edit.This SP has two select statement results. I want to use only second results. How can I achieve this without editing.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't change a SP's behavior without changing it.

Comment: Just use the second result set, ignoring the first one, if that's all what you want.

Comment: Use it where? How do you want to use it?

Comment: Aside from @jarlh's response, if you can't edit the SP (for instance, you don't have permissions), the only other way to change output is to create a copy and edit it.

Comment: If you are using ADO you can use NextRecordSet method https://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_rs_nextrecordset.asp

Comment: I want to use this data  in PowerbI

Answer (score 0):

If your server is configured for DATA ACCESS you can use this

```
SELECT groupID, value1, ID 
FROM OPENQUERY (MYSERVER, 'EXEC myStoreProcedure')
```

allowing you to to chose columns from select statements as though they were a table.

Comment: For more information on OPENQUERY and also Alternative Solutions give this article a look http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#OPENQUERY